# Given a domain, lookup its hosting provider using JAVA or PYTHON

Tags: java, python, hosting, provider

Given a domain how do you lookup its hosting provider. I have done nslookups for IPs in Java before but is there a way to get the hosting provider as well? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import org.xbill.DNS.ExtendedResolver;
import org.xbill.DNS.Lookup;
import org.xbill.DNS.Name;
import org.xbill.DNS.PTRRecord;
import org.xbill.DNS.Record;
import org.xbill.DNS.Resolver;
import org.xbill.DNS.ReverseMap;
import org.xbill.DNS.Type;

public class FindDomain {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("LOCAL ADDRESS : " + address.getHostAddress());
    System.out.println("LOCAL HOST : " + address.getHostName());

    InetAddress ipAddress = java.net.InetAddress.getByName("www.javadiscover.com");
    String ip = ipAddress.getHostAddress();
    System.out.println("\nJAVADISCOVER IP : " + ip);

    final InetAddress ip2 = InetAddress.getByName("74.125.135.121");
    final byte[] bytes = ip2.getAddress();
    final String host = getHostByIPAddress(bytes);
    System.out.println("\nJAVADISCOVER HOST : " + host);

   } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.out.println("Host NOT Avaialble");
   }

  }

  public static String getHostByIPAddress(byte[] addr) throws UnknownHostException {

   Name name = ReverseMap.fromAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(addr));

   // OPEN DNS SERVERS
   final String[] openDNS = new String[] {"208.67.222.222", "208.67.220.220"};
   final Resolver resolver = new ExtendedResolver(openDNS);
   final Lookup lookUp = new Lookup(name, Type.PTR);
   lookUp.setResolver(resolver);
   Record[] records = lookUp.run();
   if (records == null) {
    throw new UnknownHostException();
   }
   return ((PTRRecord) records[0]).getTarget().toString();
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
LOCAL ADDRESS : 10.70.50.16
LOCAL HOST : anandkumar-inl

IP : 74.125.135.121

HOST : ni-in-f121.1e100.net.
```

[Source](http://javadiscover.blogspot.in/2013/07/ip-and-domain-name-lookup-using-java.html)